# What does "$(-1/2)_k$" mean in this expression related to incomplete elliptic integrals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I've found an approximation definition for an incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind which uses the notation
$$ \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)_k. $$

I haven't seen this notation before.  Can someone explain this to me?

The complete formula, from the [Wolfram documentation for the `EllipticE()` function](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html), is shown below:

[image: The formula]

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Depending on context, it might be the Pochammer Symbol denoting the [fallling factorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html).  $(-\frac{1}{2})_k = (-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})(-\frac{5}{2})\cdots(-\frac{1}{2}-k+1)$

Comment: $(\alpha)_n$ on WA refers to the rising factorial not the falling factorial. $(\alpha)_n = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} ( \alpha+k )$. So
$\left(-\frac12\right)_n = \left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12 + 1\right)\cdots\left(-\frac12 + n - 1\right)$

Comment: @achillehui From what I can see, both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) & [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html) take $(\alpha)_n$ to denote the falling factorial.

Comment: @J.G. On some of the links of WA, if you click on the image definition, it will bring you to a page with the definition in WA functions. On one of them, I find it maps the $(a)_n$ to $Pochhammer[a,n]$, if you follow the definition of that on WA, it will ultimately get to the rising factorial.

Comment: @J.G. It depends on context.  The notation $(x)_n$ typically denotes the rising factorial when working with special functions (e.g. Bessel functions, hypergeometric series, etc), but the falling factorial in combinatorics.  Given that the question is about elliptic integrals (as implemented in Mathematica), this is almost certainly the rising factorial.  This is backed up by chasing down the definitions of other functions in Mathematica, as achille hui has suggested.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that both the Wikipedia article and MathWorld page linked by @J.G. discuss the ambiguity of the notation.

Comment: Please explain what WA is.

Comment: @Sequoia WA likely means Wolfram|alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly the [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).  For $x \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, this is defined by the formula
$$ (x)_k = x(x+1)(x+2)\dotsb (x+k-1) = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (x+j) = \frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}, $$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function (which generalizes the factorial function).  This is also sometimes called the "rising factorial."

Note that this is not the best notation.  Even the above linked MathWorld article makes this point:

> The Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n$ ... for $n\ge 0$ is an unfortunate notation used in the **theory of special functions** for the rising factorial, also known as the rising factorial power or ascending factorial. ... In combinatorics, the notation $x^{(n)}$, $\langle x\rangle_n$, or $x^{n}$ is used for the rising factorial, while $(x)_n$ or $x^n$ denotes the falling factorial. Extreme caution is therefore needed in interpreting the notations $(x)_n$ and $x^{(n)}$.
>
> [emphasis mine; references removed for readability]

However, in the context of elliptic integrals (which are among the functions studied in the "theory of special functions" alluded to in the above quoted material), the correct interpretation is likely the rising factorial.  Note that in the documentation linked in the question, one of the representations of the elliptic integral $E(z \mid m)$ is in terms of a [hypergeometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), which can be expanded in terms of the rising factorial.

Comment: It works perfectly.  The last hours were exactly this issue with the ambiguous definition of the Pochhammer symbol.  Thanks to all.